# Making Menu Collapsed By Default

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I am working on a Drupal Site, and for some reason when I came back from the weekend, one of my menu's on the site is automatically expanded now by default. I sifted through the css and php and couldn't find anything that stuck out. Is there a way through css, javascript, jquery, or php to have the menu automatically collapsed by default. I prefer css, but I can do any of the other methods. Here is a screen shot:

[image: Menu Expanded Screenshot]

**Here is the css**

```
ul.menu li {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

 }
```

Comment: We can't possibly help you unless we see the code you're using to expand and collapse your menus.

Comment: is it possible that the 'expanded' checkbox for these menu items in drupal is checked?

Comment: That would work, but then my top menu won't drop down. I need just the bottom menu to be uncollapsed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it possible that the 'expanded' checkbox for these menu items in drupal is checked? The menus look to be appropriately expanded, so I'd look to drupal first.